# PowerBI Dax Group and (Unique) Count

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this

| Planner | Supplier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Siemens |
| 1 | Müller |
| 1 | Siemens |
| 2 | Müller |
| 3 | Siemens |
| 3 | Müller |
| 3 | Müller |
| 3 | Müller |
| 4 | Siemens |
| 4 | Koch |

I have different Planners and they have used different suppliers. I want to count the unique Suppliers depending on the Planner. My Target is to get the following Output:

| Planner | Different Supplier used |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

So I need to count unique suppliers by Planner. I am doing this in DAX

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple **measure**:

```
=
DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Supplier] )
```

which you can then include in a visual together with the *Planner* field.